# R xml parsing - with only attribute

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, xml2

I'm trying to do some [text mining to elsevier articles](https://dev.elsevier.com/tecdoc_text_mining.html). I had downloaded the articles in XML format and i successfully used the XML2 library to read the text I needed.

My problem is to get data from the attribute fields, like this one:

`<ce:date-received day="17" month="11" year="2016"/>`

Reading the file `xx <- read_xml(filename)` and then trying to call `xml_find_all(xx, ".//ce:date-received")` isn't working (no results). `xml_attr(xx,"day")` isn't working either.

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634155/parse-nested-xml-with-namespaces-in-r You need to be careful with those namespaces (the "ce:" part). It would be easier to help if you actually put a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself that we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Great, thanks. that answer did help.